# Computational aspect of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

One of the examples online is about how to write [the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm from scratch](http://gradientdescending.com/metropolis-hastings-algorithm-from-scratch/). This tutorial uses a linear regression model as an example. Estimate three parameters: an intercept, a slope, and a standard deviation.

The code in that tutorial

1. proposes three candidate samples (`theta_star`) from proposal distribution (normal distribution),
2. calculates posterior (a number): `sum(loglikelihoods)` + `b0_prior` + `b1_prior` + `sd_prior` (all on log scale),
3. calculates the acceptance probability (a number) and compares it with a random number.
4. accepts all the three elements or rejects them all.

Can I use the alternative way below? Say, if I calculate the posterior respectively like

```
`sum(loglikelihoods)` + `b0_prior`
`sum(loglikelihoods)` + `b1_prior`
`sum(loglikelihoods)` + `sd_prior`
```

where the three `sum(loglikelihoods)` above are same in value. Only calculated once, not re-calculated three times.

Then I get the posterior (3 by 1 vector), calculate acceptance probability (3 by 1 vector), and compare them with three random numbers. So the three elements are updated respectively. Not accept all or reject all.

Is this modified procedure still a valid Metropolis-Hastings algorithm? I feel my question is related with [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/566520/how-can-i-find-the-acceptance-probability-for-a-joint-metropolis-hastings-propos), but not sure the above is correct in principle and theory.

Comment: A second comment is that changing one component of the parameter $\theta$ at a time, $\beta_0$ then $\beta_1$ then $\sigma$ is called Gibbs sampling.

Comment: Sorry, they are typos. Allow me to edit  the question again.

Comment: The general description of Metropolis-Hastings in the reference is confusing, the acceptance ratio should involve the proposal density. I suggest you instead read a genuine textbook on the topic.

Comment: Thank you, Professor. I just used that post as example to ask my question. As your second comment means, my procedure is simply Gibbs sampling? It lets me want to ask: Gibbs sampling updates element by element by conditional distributions. That is, update theta at a time, then beta_0, then sigma. This procedure needs to calculate the loglikelihood three times, right? In my question, I only calculate loglikelihood once and update the three elements in parallel. It seems not the same. I wonder if the modified procedure in my question is correct or not. Thank you for your kind reply above.

Comment: Yes you need to update the likelihood three times. Otherwise it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Above is an illustration of the difference between both approaches, when applied to a toy target distribution

```
a<-function(b){
dnorm(b[1],l=TRUE)+
dnorm(b[2]-.5*b[1]^2,sd=.7,l=TRUE)+
dnorm(b[3]+1.2*b[2]+.5*b[1]^2,sd=.5,l=TRUE)}
```

The original (and correct) Metropolis-within-Gibbs scheme

```
g<-function(T=1e4){
  o=matrix(rnorm(3),T,3)
  for(t in 2:T){
    p=o[t-1,]+rnorm(3)
    o[t,]=p+(log(runif(1))>a(p)-a(o[t-1,]))*(o[t-1,]-p)}
  return(o)}
```

produces golden dots/samples. The one-choice at a time alternative

```
k<-function(T=1e4){
   o=matrix(rnorm(3),T,3)
   for(t in 2:T){
      p=o[t-1,]+rnorm(3)
      b=a(p);d=a(o[t-1,])
      for(i in 1:3) o[t,i]=p[i]+(log(runif(1))>b-d)*(o[t-1,i]-p[i])}
   return(o)}
```

produces red dots/samples. (Upper row is comparing samples two coordinates at a time, lower row is comparing density estimates one coordinate at a time.)

Comment: Really thank you for the time to provide a toy example! Does it mean the one-choice-at-a-time alternative (incorrect method) cannot produce an approximate distribution to the true distribution? If so, it would be clear to impose true distribution on the density plots.